# If $X \subseteq A \cup B \implies X \subseteq A$ or $X \subseteq B$ then $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $X \subseteq A \cup B \implies X \subseteq A$ or $X \subseteq B$. I want to show that this means $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$.

It is clear to me why this is not true in general (i.e. why $X \subseteq A \cup B$ does not normally mean that $X \subseteq A$ or $X \subseteq B$) but I am not sure how to put the logic together to prove that this implication means that one of $A,B$ is a subset of the other.

Answer (score 4):

Prove the contrapositive.  Assume that neither $A$ nor $B$ is contained in the other.  Then $\exists x \in A \setminus B \text{ and } \exists y \in B \setminus A, \text{ so }X= \{x, y \} \subseteq A \cup B \text{ but } X \not\subseteq A \text{ and } X \not\subseteq B$ and the implication on the left fails.

Answer (score 2):

More precisely the condition on the sets $A$ and $B$ is

> for all $X$, $X\subseteq A\cup B\implies X\subseteq A$ or $X\subseteq B$

and your task is to prove that either $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$.

Hint: try with $X=A\cup B$